# How to iterate over values in dictionary which each key has multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{4722: "['children', 'dance', 'education','technology', 'teaching']",
3200: "['alternative energy', 'sustainability', 'technology']",
1636: "['computers', 'performance', 'simplicity', 'software', 'ice']",
1697: "['MacArthur grant', 'inequality', 'technology', 'pollution']"}
```

Now I want to find the word 'technology' in each row and sum the keys. Like here I should have the sum of 4722 + 3200 + 1697 .

Can anyone help me please?

I should mention that my original data frame has 2000 rows.

Comment: Are your dictionary values really supposed to be strings containing a textual version of a list - rather than actual lists???

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert those list-strings to actual Python lists, which will make them easier to work with.

Comment: Actually does not matter whether values is string, list of strings, or string of lists, because `'technology' in v` can cover all situations :)

Comment: does not forget to accept the answer. I like Rob's answer, so accept his one

Comment: `"technology" in v` works in this specific instance, but only by coincidence. It is prone to false positives if there are other items that *include* the word "technology" but do not match it exactly. You could tighten it up by including the quotes, though it'd still be inelegant, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_data = {
    4722: "['children', 'dance', 'education','technology', 'teaching']",
    3200: "['alternative energy', 'sustainability', 'technology']",
    1636: "['computers', 'performance', 'simplicity', 'software', 'ice']",
    1697: "['MacArthur grant', 'inequality', 'technology', 'pollution']"
}

sum_up = 0
for k, v in your_data.items():
    if 'technology' in v:
        sum_up += k

print('sum_up:', sum_up)
```

Comment: This will add all the keys, which the OP doesnt want. Only keys containing `'technology'` in their value list.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `sum()` built-in function, passing an appropriate generator expression: `sum(k for k,v in d.items() if 'technology' in v)` (n.b. use `d.iteritems()` in Python2).

Runnable demo:

```
d = {
    4722: "['children', 'dance', 'education','technology', 'teaching']",
    3200: "['alternative energy', 'sustainability', 'technology']",
    1636: "['computers', 'performance', 'simplicity', 'software', 'ice']",
    1697: "['MacArthur grant', 'inequality', 'technology', 'pollution']"
}

result = sum(k for k,v in d.items() if 'technology' in v)
assert result == 9619
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items
- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression

Comment: It gives me this error: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable